# Cursor not moving in tree insert function, found in provided header file that has constructor and class definition. How can I move the cursor forward?

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree, binary-search-tree

The assignment requires that I write the code for an Insert, Print and Find functions in the already provided tree header file. It's a very simple search tree for ints. Here is the header file:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Tree {
    Tree    *left;
    Tree    *right;
    int     node;

    static std::map<int, Tree*> allNodes;

public:
    Tree(int n, Tree *l=0, Tree *r=0) : left(l), right(r), node(n) {
        allNodes[n] = this;
    }

    int GetNode() { return node; }

    void Insert(Tree *newnode) {
        // insert code to Insert newnode into tree pointed to by this... return the tree
        // My own code // cout<<this->node;

        if( newnode->node == this->node ){}
             // skip dup

        //Everything after is also my code

        else if (newnode->node < this->node){
            left = newnode;
            cout<<"left"<<left->node<<endl;   
        }
        else if (newnode->node > this->node){
            right = newnode;
            cout<<"right"<<right->node<<endl;
        }

    }
```

Here is the code that implements it(I wrote the code at the very bottom):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include "trav.h"

std::map<int, Tree*> Tree::allNodes;

// trav print
// trav find X

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( argc < 2 )
        return 0;

    string cmd(argv[1]);

    // READ IN THE INTEGERS
    vector<int> ids;
    int input;
    while( cin >> input ) {
        ids.push_back( input );
    }

    // MAKE NODES FROM THE INTEGERS
    vector<Tree*> nodes;
    for( int id: ids ) {
        nodes.push_back( new Tree(id) );
    }

    if( ids.size() == 0 )
        return -1;

    // PUT NODES INTO A TREE USING Insert
    Tree *theTree = nodes[0];

    if( theTree == nullptr )
        return -1;

    for( auto n : nodes ) {
        //My code// theTree->Insert(n);
    }

    // PRINT TREE
    if( cmd == "print" ) {
        theTree->Print();
    }


    /*if (cmd == "find") {
        string no = argv[2];
        int num = atoi(no);
        int result = theTree-> find(num);
        if(result!=0)
            cout<<num<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"-1"<<endl;
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
3232left8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
32left3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32left5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32left9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32right40                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
32right100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
32right632                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
32left1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32left9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32left9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32left3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32left2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
32right64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
32right43                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
43                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
32
```

Those last 3 numbers are from my print function.
The cursor doesn't appear to be moving forward. I've tried setting this=left, which returns an error. What can I do? And I'm not sure how to use the allNodes. Do I implement it in the insert function?

Comment: I don't really see a question anywhere.

Comment: Edited and included in title. I'm confused about how I can actually move the cursor forward, and also about what to do with the provided map. Do I store all the values into the map?

Comment: That depends. Where did you get the code from? What can/can't you change about the code?

Comment: The parts I did not write were provided as starter code for the assignment. I indicate as comments which parts I added, needless to say the only functions I insert code into are the Insert, Print and Find functions. That's all I believe I'm allowed to edit.